# Revisions/version control

Tags: nodes

I am using the Diff (http://drupal.org/project/diff ) module for Revisions. It displays the revisions by date/time. However, the client has asked for incremental version labelling. Can this be achieved in Drupal?

Comment: I don't understand what it is that you want to do.

Comment: I agree with @Letharion - could you perhaps edit some more details into your question?